# Install curl command on Ubuntu Snappy Core

Tags: dns, cron, ubuntu-core, curl, nextcloud

I'm trying to set up a cron job to point Duckdns to my Nextcloud server. The server is a raspberry pi 3 running Ubuntu Snappy Core. I'm following the steps at http://www.duckdns.org/install.jsp . I've been looking around the internet, and I can't find any way to install curl as a snap. Does anyone know of an alternative to the curl command that I can use? Or, could someone walk me through building a snap for the curl command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Core doesn't have cron, so even if you get a snap for curl you won't be able to automate this. When approaching this type of issue, creating a snap for the product you need is the perfect step. Basically, create a snap that includes curl, but also includes a service that runs every five minutes to update the DNS records.

This one is particularly easy, so I [threw one together](https://github.com/kyrofa/duckdns) for you to learn with. The README outlines how to use it, but I'll reproduce it here. Install it with:

```
$ sudo snap install duckdns-kyrofa
```

Configure it by providing your token:

```
$ snap set duckdns-kyrofa token=<secret>
```

And configure your domain name list (comma-separated, no spaces):

```
$ snap set duckdns-kyrofa domains=domain1.com,domain2.com
```

That's it. The daemon runs every five minutes. Check the journal for output, including any problems:

```
$ journalctl -u snap.duckdns-kyrofa.duckdns.service
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm still learning a lot about building snaps and about the linux environment. I'm going to read and build this code and comment back here to tell how it worked. You're a big help!